Go to Declaration or Usages behaviour change in new Rider(noticed in 2024.3 EAP4)
I use an "Go to Declaration or Usages" quite often as it convenient option to go with while Debugging/Researching/Etc.
When you click first time(I use CMND+MOUSE0CLICK) on any class member, it leads you to it's declaration.
When you click it second time it supposed to open usages window.
But I've noticed that second step doesn't work as it used to be.
Now it shows two extra windowed steps to achieve the same, asking me for doing search outside of solution.
Has anyone notices the same?
For me it's most used hotkey, and I struggle to understand why they would change it in such way.
Screenshots are attached.
OS X, Rider EAP 2024.3 EAP 4

